# review board, post-review and a deleted file

Tags: review-board

Googling and reading Review Board's documentation (and bugging coworkers) hasn't solved this problem so far.

I'm using Review Board (1.5) for code review. When doing a command line post-review, Review Board doesn't like it when I've deleted a file (svn del, that is).

In other words, r1 for example, had foo.js but r3 has had foo.js svn deleted during a reorganization and cleanup of files no longer used.

When doing the post-review, the error message is:

```
server$ post-review --revision-range=r1:r3 --submit-as="jody"
Failed to execute command: ['svn', 'info', 'js/app.conf.js']
['js/foo.js:  (Not a versioned resource)\n', '\n', 'svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details\n']
```

How can one svn del an unneeded file but move forward with the post-review without the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is still a bug with review board. I ran into a similar situation but thankfully my latest commit consisted of just deleting one file.

so i could just do post-review --revison-range 192:205 , i.e range one commit earlier than the delete if the commit where i deleted the file was 206.

Answer (score 1):

One hack that worked for me was to reset the working copy to the revision where the file still exists (`svn update -r1`) and post the review from there.  I guess that might not work if you've also added new files along with the deletions.